# postgres not using btree_gist index

Tags: postgresql, btree-gist

I have a huge table with a primary key and a btree_gist index.
When I query for the columns in the btree_gist index, I would expect that the index is used and the query performs quite fast. However, the optimiser always performs an index scan on the primary key and the filters.

Example:

```
create table test1 (
    id1 bigint not null,
    id2 bigint not null,
    validtime tstzrange not null,
    data float);
alter table test1 add constraint pk_test1 primary key (id1, id2, validtime);
alter table test1 add constraint ex_test1_validtime exclude using gist (id1 with =, id2 with =, validtime with &&);
```

The table contains about 1.2 billion rows, the query I wonder about returns only some hundred rows, but takes a long time:

```
select * from test1 where id1=1 and id2=1 and validtime && '[2020-01-01,2020-02-01)';
(about 3s)
```

Query plan:

```
explain select * from test1 where id1=1 and id2=1 and validtime && '[2020-01-01,2020-02-01)';
                                        QUERY PLAN                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using pk_test1 on test1  (cost=0.70..24.68 rows=1 width=46)
   Index Cond: ((id1 = 1) AND (id2 = 1))
   Filter: (validtime && '["2020-01-01 00:00:00+00","2020-02-01 00:00:00+00")'::tstzrange)
```

The reason for the bad performance is obviously that ten thousands of rows are read and filtered in the time criteria.

I wonder why postgres does not use the btree_gist.

---

I have another, slightly different table where the btree_gist is used but in a very different way than I would expect. This table has about 160 million rows.

```
create table test2 (
    id1 bigint not null,
    validtime tstzrange not null);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
alter table test2 add constraint pk_test2 primary key (id1, validtime);
alter table test2 add constraint ex_test2_validtime exclude using gist (id1 with =, validtime with &&);
```

Here, the execution plan looks like this:

```
select * from test2 where id1=1 and validtime && '[2020-01-01,2020-02-01)';
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test2  (cost=1933.19..1937.20 rows=1 width=62)
   Recheck Cond: ((id1 = 1) AND (validtime && '["2020-01-01 00:00:00+00","2020-02-01 00:00:00+00")'::tstzrange))
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1933.19..1933.19 rows=1 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_test2  (cost=0.00..574.20 rows=11417 width=0)
               Index Cond: (id1 = 1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ex_test2_validtime  (cost=0.00..1358.74 rows=17019 width=0)
               Index Cond: (validtime && '["2020-01-01 00:00:00+00","2020-02-01 00:00:00+00")'::tstzrange)
```

Why the two bitmap index scans, couldn't it all be done with one index scan using the btree_gist index?

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. About your first query: is the desired index used if you drop the other one?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test much with test1 currently, as I'm building a new index and the table is locked.
I created another test table (with no data) to try without the primary key. The query plan shows then a bitmap scan on the btree_gist index, but only with the time criteria, then a bitmap heap scan on the table and filtering for the id1 and id2 criteria. I guess this will be a disaster on the real, billion row table (although better than a full table scan).
What I don't understand is why the id1 and id2 criteria don't go into the btree_gist index scan. I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but I want to add some background as to why this happens.

An index in PostgreSQL only supports the operators that belong to the [operator family of its operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xindex.html#XINDEX-OPFAMILY). For GiST indexes on `bigint`, that is

```
SELECT ao.amoplefttype::regtype,
       op.oprname,
       ao.amoprighttype::regtype
FROM pg_opfamily AS of
   JOIN pg_am AS am ON of.opfmethod = am.oid
   JOIN pg_amop AS ao ON of.oid = ao.amopfamily
   JOIN pg_operator AS op ON ao.amopopr = op.oid
WHERE am.amname = 'gist'
  AND ao.amoplefttype = 'bigint'::regtype;

 amoplefttype │ oprname │ amoprighttype 
══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════════
 bigint       │ <       │ bigint
 bigint       │ <=      │ bigint
 bigint       │ =       │ bigint
 bigint       │ >=      │ bigint
 bigint       │ >       │ bigint
 bigint       │ <>      │ bigint
 bigint       │ <->     │ bigint
(7 rows)
```

which explains why you have to cast to `bigint` for the index to get used.

This is surprising if you are used to PostgreSQL, because PostgreSQL does not need such a cast with a B-tree index. The explanation is that the operator family for `btree` has more operators:

```
SELECT ao.amoplefttype::regtype,
       op.oprname,
       ao.amoprighttype::regtype
FROM pg_opfamily AS of
   JOIN pg_am AS am ON of.opfmethod = am.oid
   JOIN pg_amop AS ao ON of.oid = ao.amopfamily
   JOIN pg_operator AS op ON ao.amopopr = op.oid
WHERE am.amname = 'btree'
  AND ao.amoplefttype = 'bigint'::regtype;

 amoplefttype │ oprname │ amoprighttype 
══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════════
 bigint       │ <       │ bigint
 bigint       │ <=      │ bigint
 bigint       │ =       │ bigint
 bigint       │ >=      │ bigint
 bigint       │ >       │ bigint
 bigint       │ <       │ smallint
 bigint       │ <=      │ smallint
 bigint       │ =       │ smallint
 bigint       │ >=      │ smallint
 bigint       │ >       │ smallint
 bigint       │ <       │ integer
 bigint       │ <=      │ integer
 bigint       │ =       │ integer
 bigint       │ >=      │ integer
 bigint       │ >       │ integer
(15 rows)
```

and equality comparison between `bigint` and `integer` is among them.

You could have used a regular B-tree index to support your query if you had written the condition using `>=` and `<` rather than `&&`, which would make the cast unnecessary, but of course you don't want to create a second index if there is already the index from the exclusion constraint.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found it:

The indexes are not used because of a type mismatch between the query and the index. It's actually mentioned all over the places, but I just read over it.

`1` is obviously not a `bigint`! Funny that the cast happens automatically for using the btree primary key, but not the btree_gist.

Anyhow, everything works as expected with this query:

```
select * from test1
where id1=1::bigint and id2=1::bigint
and validtime && '[2020-01-01,2020-02-01)';
```

Learning this cost me some hours, I will never forget it again!